# Symfony Security

Tags: php, symfony

My user registration with api function and begin I redirect this user from user profile and I need add this user to authentication. I try this - add in security provider(user) and firewall(main) and create and call service with help PreAuthenticatedToken. Service work fine, but when after service I redirect in user profile and symfony or session DIE, no information error or something like that. Help please, what I'am doing wrong?

this I have in session in _security_main:

```
C:74:"Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\PreAuthenticatedToken":416:{a:3:{i:0;s:7:"s@s.com";i:1;s:4:"main";i:2;s:364:"a:4:{i:0;O:47:"Proxies\__CG__\Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users":4:{s:17:"__isInitialized__";b:1;s:5:"
```

security:

```
security:
encoders:
    Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users:
        algorithm:        sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1

    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_CLIENT:   ROLE_CLIENT
    ROLE_COMPANY:  ROLE_COMPANY,
    ROLE_FREELANCER: ROLE_FREELANCER
    ROLE_ADMIN:    [ROLE_FREELANCER, ROLE_COMPANY, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_CLIENT]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_MODERATOR, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    user:
        entity:
            class: ArtelProfileBundle:Users
            property: securitytoken
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [user_db, in_memory]
            providers: [user_dev, in_memory]
    user_db:
        entity: { class: Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users, property: email }
    in_memory:
       memory:
         users:
            admin_tyty: { password: adminpass_tyty, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }


firewalls:
    default:
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
        logout:
              path:   /logout
              invalidate_session: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            provider: user
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
            username_parameter: login[securitytoken]
            use_referer: true
        logout:
            path: logout
            target: /

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/sonata-admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/company, roles:  ROLE_COMPANY  }
    - { path: ^/profile, roles:  ROLE_FREELANCER  }
    - { path: ^/clients, roles:  ROLE_CLIENT  }
    - { path: ^/customer/developers/profile/get, roles:  IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY  }
    - { path: ^/customer/developers/bit, roles:  IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY  }
    - { path: ^/customer/developers/bitGet, roles:  IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY  }
```

and my service for automatic authentication:

```
        <service id="artel.profile.authenticator"
             class="Artel\ProfileBundle\Helper\Authenticator">
        <argument type="service" id="security.token_storage" />
    </service>

<?php
 namespace Artel\ProfileBundle\Helper;

 use Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users;
 use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
 use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\PreAuthenticatedToken;
 use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;

 class Authenticator
{
/**
 * @var TokenStorage
 */
private $tokenStorage;
public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}

public function addAuth(Users $user)
{
    $token = new PreAuthenticatedToken($user, $user->getSecuritytoken(), 'main', $user->getRoles());
    $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);
    $this->session->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
}
```

**UPDATE**
when I change

```
    public function addAuth(Users $user)
{
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
    $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);
}
```

I have but error and when I calling $this->getUser() I have user and in debug panel I have information about user. This is right or maybe this not good away ?

Comment: Are you trying to redirect user after login?